# python_" .txt" files can not be created

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, save, web-crawler

" .txt " files can not be created.

The code has been created, but the file is not created.

I've been advised to use " pickle ".

But I don't know how to use " pickle. "

How can I use this code to save it as a file

Also, I would like to place the number in order to save.

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

search_term = 'word1'
search_term2= 'word2'
search_term3='word3'

lat = "xxxx"
lon = "xxxx"
radius = "xxxx"
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)

API_key = "xxxx"
API_secret = "xxxx"
Access_token = "xxxx"
Access_token_secret = "xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)

data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/workk2.txt", mode='w')   
data = {}   
i = 0       

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text   
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')  
    i += 1

wfile.close()
```

Comment: "_But I don't know how to use " pickle. "_" What stops you from reading a tutorial?

Comment: This site has an example of using pickle and is self-explanatory.  Enjoy! https://pythontips.com/2013/08/02/what-is-pickle-in-python/